# Hiding an input file inside a button Semantic-UI

Tags: html, css, input, semantic-ui

Is there a way to make this work using Semantic-ui?

I have this button, which look OK, but the input file never gets called.

```
<div class="ui icon big button">
        <i class="cloud icon"></i>
        <input type="file" id="hidde-new-file" style="display: none">
 </div>
```

Comment: Since `file` input is readonly, why would you hide it ? Do you want to show it only when the cursor is above an element ? And can you make a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend adding a label pointing to your hidden input. Labels trigger their input when clicked. All native without JS.

```
<div>
  <label for="hidden-new-file" class="ui icon button">
    <i class="cloud icon"></i>
    Open File
  </label>
  <input type="file" id="hidden-new-file" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Comment: I had a typo on the "for" of the label. Thanks tizis!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution :

Put your `file` input outside the `div`, add an ID to the div, then add this JavaScript :

```
$("#divUpload").on("click", function() {
   $('#hidde-new-file').click(); 
});
```

Here is [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsa8kydg/)